# VS2010 Click Once Deployment with SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 install fails

Tags: sql-server-ce, clickonce

I have a desktop app that uses Click-Once deployment with a SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 as a prerequisite. This has been working well for the last 8+ years but now client installs are failing due to SQL Server CE 3.5 being removed from MS downloads. I have no idea how to get around this problem as there are no other SQL Server CE options in the publish section of VS2010. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just include the binaries as content

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you!!! One question, does this mean every time I release an update that SQLCe will be reinstalled?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include the binaries as content with your app.

Target x86, and include the following files:

The files you need to add are:

```
sqlceca35.dll
sqlcecompact35.dll
sqlceer35EN.dll
sqlceme35.dll
sqlceoledb35.dll
sqlceqp35.dll
sqlcese35.dll
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

Much more detail in this long blog post: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you!!! One question, does this mean every time I release an update that SQLCe will be reinstalled?

Comment: It is not "installed", the engine is simply included as files with your app.

Answer (score 0):

I added binaries to the project meticulously following the instructions, deleted SQLCE from the system, compiled, uploaded checked that all files were present but installation failed saying SQLCe must be installed in the GAC before installing. So I played around checking and double checking to no avail. Then in VS2010 >Publish >Prerequisites tab I noticed the option to "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application". Selected that option, published and presto all the prerequisite files were added to the Publish location and it all works now as it did before.
Thanks for help as I wouldn't have figured this out without it. Hope this answer helps someone else.